How does Prim MST choose the next edge?
I am having difficulty implementing Prim's algorithm with priority queue in Python.
I wish to verify if my understanding on Prim is correct.
Consider the case where the source vertex is 0.

Find 0's neighbors in the graph
Add 0's neighbors to the priority queue
Pop out the minimum edge in the PQ to add to MST (By default, heapq.pop returns the min)
If the minimum edge is 0->1, now repeat the process by adding 1's neighbors and again popping accordingly until all vertices are in the priority queue

If there is any nuance I am neglecting to consider, please let me know.
I read various articles about Prim algorithm and its implementation. I just someone else to tell me if it is correct or not because if I try to code with the wrong understanding, I will be debugging forever.
